# append class to ampersands but exclude certain area

Tags: jquery

Have the ampersand's wrapping in the proper class but now I want to exclude one class to not be touched. The class that needs to be excluded is ".highlight"

Here is the working line:

```
$("body *").replaceText( /&/gi, '<b class="ampersand">' + '&' + '</b>' );
```

Comment: I doubt you need to do a case-insensitive search when looking for "&".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:not` modifier:

```
$("body *:not(.highlight):contains(&)").replaceText(/&/g, '<b class="ampersand">&</b>' );
```

I also added the `:contains` check, so it won't waste time processing elements that don't need any changes.